# Setting the internal buffer used by a standard stream (pubsetbuf)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stream

I'm writing a subroutine that needs to write data to an existing buffer, and I would like to use the [`stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) class to facilitate the formatting of the data.

Initially, I used the following code to copy the contents of the stream into the buffer, but would like to avoid this solution as it copies too much data.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

void FillBuffer(char* buffer, unsigned int size)
{
    std::stringstream message;
    message << "Hello" << std::endl;
    message << "World!" << std::endl;

    std::string messageText(message.str());
    std::copy(messageText.begin(), messageText.end(), buffer);
}
```

This is when I discovered the [`streambuf::pubsetbuf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pubsetbuf) method and simply rewrote the above code as follows.

```
#include <sstream>

void FillBuffer(char* buffer, unsigned int size)
{
    std::stringstream message;
    message.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer, size);

    message << "Hello" << std::endl;
    message << "World!" << std::endl;
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work under the C++ standard library implementation that ships with Visual Studio 2008; `buffer` remains unchanged.

I looked at the implementation of `pubsetbuf` and it turns out that it literally "does nothing".

```
virtual _Myt *__CLR_OR_THIS_CALL setbuf(_Elem *, streamsize)
{   // offer buffer to external agent (do nothing)
    return (this);
}
```

This appears to be a limitation of the given C++ standard library implementation.  What is the recommended way to configure a stream to write its contents to a given buffer?

Comment: @Steve I am using VS2008 also, but it is implemented!

Comment: @Arak -- My implementation of `pubsetbuf()` forwards to the private `setbuf()` operation, implemented as above.  Can you confirm that your implementation is different?

Comment: This still holds true in VS2010

Comment: Still true in VS2017

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After some more research on this problem, and scrutiny of my code, I came across [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448467/initializing-a-c-stdistringstream-from-an-in-memory-buffer/1449527#1449527) suggesting the use of a hand-coded [`std::streambuf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/) class.  The idea behind this code is to create a `streambuf` that initializes its internals to refer to the given buffer.  The code is as follows.

```
#include <streambuf>

template <typename char_type>
struct ostreambuf : public std::basic_streambuf<char_type, std::char_traits<char_type> >
{
    ostreambuf(char_type* buffer, std::streamsize bufferLength)
    {
        // set the "put" pointer the start of the buffer and record it's length.
        setp(buffer, buffer + bufferLength);
    }
};
```

Now if you look at [my original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494182/setting-the-internal-buffer-used-by-a-standard-stream-pubsetbuf), you will notice that I didn't really need a `stringstream` to begin with.  All I really needed was a way to write to an external buffer using the [IOStream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/) library and [`std::ostream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/) is a much better type to address this problem.  Incidentally, I suspect this is how the [array_sink](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html?path=4.2.1.3) type from [Boost.IOStreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) is implemented.

Here is the modified code that uses my `ostreambuf` type.

```
#include <ostream>
#include "ostreambuf.h"  // file including ostreambuf struct from above.

void FillBuffer(char* buffer, unsigned int size)
{
    ostreambuf<char> ostreamBuffer(buffer, size);
    std::ostream messageStream(&ostreamBuffer);

    messageStream << "Hello" << std::endl;
    messageStream << "World!" << std::endl;
}
```

For a more complex example see:

- [What's wrong with this stream buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116158/whats-wrong-with-this-stream-buffer)

Comment: Does this code not have an issue with null terminating the buffer ? Considering that this is a hello world example I guess the buffer should be null terminated.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a job for the (officially deprecated, but still standard) [std::strstream](http://www2.roguewave.com/support/docs/leif/sourcepro/html/stdlibref/strstream.html). You could also look at the [Boost.IOStreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) library, [array_sink](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html?path=4.2.1.3), in particular.

Comment: Isn't std::strstream simply a synonym of std::stringstream? Why would it be implemented any differently?

Comment: No, it is more efficient (and tricky to use) as it allows the user to directly provide and manage the buffer. See option #4 in http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm, for example.

Comment: @Clifford: http://kera.name/articles/2008/09/tomalaks-tuesday-tip-2-string-streams/

Answer (score 0):

As the link you posted says: "specific implementations may vary".

Can you not simply return the std::string object and then use std::string::c_str() or std::string::data() at the point the char buffer is required?

Alternatively use sprintf() from the C library, then the whole operation can be completed in the buffer passed. Since that way may result in potential buffer overrun, and you are using Visual C++, you might consider [sprintf_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not use `c_str()` as the buffer is owned by another type. I'm expected to fill that buffer with something so that the other type may operate upon it. `sprintf_s()` will work well and I shouldn't have a problem using that.