# c++ rdbuf()->pubsetbuf for a stream, using a char buffer. I have no data in it 

Tags: c++, stringstream

Maybe can exist a better solution, but this is what I have:

```
mybuffer   = new char[265536](); // all to zero 
the_stream = new stringstream ;
the_stream->rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(mybuffer,265536);
```

I have a put function:

```
template <class TTput_stream>
void W_inpout::W_stream::put (TTput_stream &value) {   
   int a =  sizeof value;
   const char * buffer ;
   buffer = reinterpret_cast<const char*> (&value);
   the_stream->write(buffer,sizeof value);
   loc+= sizeof value;
   if (lof<loc)  lof=loc; 
}
```

And  Get function:

```
template <class TTget_stream>
void W_inpout::W_stream::get(TTget_stream & value) {
    char * buffer ;
    buffer = reinterpret_cast< char*> (&value);
    the_stream->read(buffer, sizeof value);  
    loc=int(the_stream->tellg());
    the_stream->seekp(the_stream->tellg());
}
```

It works for me. 
If I put some values (in example one int, 2 floats, 3 doubles), I can recover them without problem (Doing a seekg before calling the get function).

But I have a problem.
I want to access to 'mybuffer' data and I discover that after some 'put' commands I keep having zeros in all the 265536 positions.

```
for (int x=0;x<265536;x++) { if (mybuffer[x]!=0) .... )
```

I dont understand what is happening.  Where is my data? Why does my buffer seems to be empty?

Comment: Can you provide code, where you put something, and then you see only zeroes?

Comment: the code is the showed at the post.
I just call : 
float x = 15: the_stream->put(15); the_stream->seekg(0); float y; the_stream->get(y)

Comment: the code is the showed at the post.
I just call : 
     float x = 15: the_stream->put(15); the_stream->seekg(0); float y; the_stream->get(y) : This works and if I check mybuffer all is zero.
(excuse me for the answer, I dont konw what is happen but I cant press enter, tab , etc )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see zeros. Checked with gcc 4.5. If you use Visual Studio, you can find this link usefull:

[Setting the internal buffer used by a standard stream (pubsetbuf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494182/setting-the-internal-buffer-used-by-a-standard-stream-pubsetbuf)

Comment: Yes, with mingw I dont see zeros. This is a VC problem. What I dont understand is why I have not warning emitted by the compiler ... (I use qt+qtcreator+ms compiler). And I dont see eany decent document showing how to use  a class extending public std::streambuf....