# stringstream->rdbuf()->pubsetbuf is not setting the buffer

Tags: c++, stl, stringstream, stringbuffer

I am trying to modify a stringbuffer of a stringstream object without having to copy a string, using the method pubsetbuf, but it is not working. I am following the documentation in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/pubsetbuf/. Here is my example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::stringstream stream("You say goodbye");
    char replace[] = {"And I say hello"};
    std::cout << stream.str() << std::endl; // Checking original contents
    stream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(replace, 16); // Should set contents here
    std::cout << stream.str() << std::endl; // But don't :(
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
You say goodbye
You say goodbye
```

I know I can use stream.str(replace), but this method copies the value of 'replace', and I don't want to make a copy.

What am I missing?

Update: I'm using VS2010

Comment: just a ridiculously quick search of SO - are you experiencing this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494182/setting-the-internal-buffer-used-by-a-standard-stream-pubsetbuf

Comment: If you are using VS, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10054396/416627) (and answer). It doesn't work like you think it does. It's implementation defined and only implemented where it makes sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the internal buffer used by a standard stream (pubsetbuf)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494182/setting-the-internal-buffer-used-by-a-standard-stream-pubsetbuf)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not should set contents. `pubsetbuf` calls `virtual setbuf`

```
basic_streambuf<charT,traits>* setbuf(charT* s, streamsize n);
```

> 15 Effects: implementation-defined, except that setbuf(0,0) has no effect.
>
> 16 Returns: this.

VS 2010. There is no overload of virtual method `setbuf` in `basic_stringbuf`, it uses default from `basic_streambuf`

```
virtual _Myt *__CLR_OR_THIS_CALL setbuf(_Elem *, streamsize)
    {   // offer buffer to external agent (do nothing)
    return (this);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I though that "specific implementations" in the documentation was referring to the concrete classes, not to specific vendor implementation. I presumed it would work well in any c++ compiler.