# I am using stringstream with my own buffer, but its str() method doesn't related to my buffer?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I want to use my own buffer zone for the stringstream, but changing the buffer twice won't expect two output just as the code shown follow.

```
std::stringstream ss;
char buffer[10];
memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof buffer);

ss.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer, sizeof buffer);
sprintf(buffer, "abcd");
std::cout << ss.str() << std::flush;

ss.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer, sizeof buffer);
sprintf(buffer, "efgh");
std::cout << ss.str() << std::flush;
```

And the result is:

```
abcd
```

After I setting the buffer to "efgh", the ss.str() doesn't show me the new content, why is that?

**And the reason why I want to directly set the internal buffer is that it should be a system call like recv.**

Now I found out that event if I change the buffer totally using pubsetbuf in the second calling, it does not change at all, remaining the previous contents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stringstream->rdbuf()->pubsetbuf is not setting the buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481463/stringstream-rdbuf-pubsetbuf-is-not-setting-the-buffer)

Answer (score 0):

ss is a different object than the "buffer" it is not a pointer to "buffer".
When you do "pubsetbuf" you copy the contents of buffer into "ss".
You might want to try using "ss<<buffer" instead anyway, it will be easier.

Comment: I have looked up some posts on this site, calling ss.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf() is kind of a common way of setting an existing buffer to a stringstream. And you said it's not. Now I am really confuse about it :)

Comment: "setting an existing buffer to a stringstream" means that it will copy the contents into the stringstream, you will need to call that function again after changing buffer.

Comment: Since this function is copying data, is it not efficient enough than simply using operator<< ?

Comment: That is not what I meant, both will copy the contents. stringstream does not hold a pointer to an external buffer and cannot be manipulated by changing a different buffer.

Comment: I have edit the post. In my case, i want to directly set my buffer. And I want this ss object be aware of that.

Comment: putting an additional pubsetbuf() call doesn't work :)

Comment: `sprintf(buffer, "efgh");
ss.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer, sizeof buffer);`

Comment: Anyway you do it when you change the value of "buffer" the value of ss will not change.

Comment: Is there any solutions? I can't change the 'recv' system call, thus I could only change the content by changing the buffer.

Comment: stringstream is a C++ object which can't anyway be used in system calls. You can only use "char*" in system calls. why do you need a "stringstream" in the first place?

Comment: I think using stringstream will be easier for parsing some string like http header:)