# How to read from RAM?

Tags: c++, file, buffer, istream

What I need to do?

I need to read the file from RAM

How I am doing it?

I use `std::istream`, because it know how to read from buffer. So, there is method that know how to read file size(according to this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6039648/5709159)

```
long getFileSize(const std::string &filename)
{
    struct stat stat_buf{};
    int rc = stat(filename.c_str(), &stat_buf);
    return rc == 0 ? stat_buf.st_size : -1;
}
```

Then I use membuf to copy bytes from file to buffer (according to this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13586356/5709159)

```
struct membuf : std::streambuf
    {
        membuf(char *base, std::ptrdiff_t n)
        {
            this->setg(base, base, base + n);
        }
    };
```

Full implementation looks like this

```
long size = getFileSize(filename);
membuf sbuf(0, size);
std::istream file(&sbuf);
```

But, I am now sure that `sbuf(0, size);` that `0` here is on the right place...

So, question is - how to set `membuf` with right size ?

Comment: Subject of your question is quite confusing.

Comment: @Slava why? I just would like to know if set membuf like I do it, is ok or not?

Comment: Because it means something completely different than question itself if it means anything. Did you use online translator?

Comment: @Slava no, but as well I am not a native speaker... I changed the title of question...

Comment: First argument is start of the buffer. You set to 0 which means it will try to read from zero address in RAM. Is that what you want? On most operating systems it will cause a crash.

Comment: Also not clear what are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to create an object of `std::istream` in such a way as to read from memory instead of a file?

Comment: Alternative way is to use `std::istringstream`.

Comment: @IlyaPopov Actually I want to copy bytes from file to RAM (as a buffer) and read from RAM instead of read from file (at least it should work if I understand it correctly).

Comment: @IlyaPopov What do you mean alternative? As far as I know isringstream not read from RAM, no?

Comment: @IlyaPopov it is exactly what this guy is talking about https://stackoverflow.com/a/13586356/5709159

Comment: Note that `long getFileSize(const std::string &filename)` is not right.  The `st_size` field of a `struct stat` is of type `off_t`.  A `long` value is not guaranteed to be large enough to hold an `off_t` value.  For example, a 32-bit system that supports files larger than 2 GB will have to have an `off_t` that's larger than the 32-bit `long` type typical on 32-bit systems.  Such a system likely has a 64-bit `off_t`.  And then there's Windows, where `long` is 32-bits even for a 64-bit process...

Comment: Regarding your question, are you trying to copy data from the file into RAM, or from a known location in RAM into the file?  Or, are you trying to treat a known area of memory as a file and read from it as if that memory were a file?  If that last, this might be helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849749/what-is-the-difference-between-fmemopen-and-open-memstream

Comment: @AndrewHenle So, if I understood you correctly you mean that this SO answer is not correct `about getSize()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/6039648/5709159 , right?

Comment: @AndrewHenle actually I would like to do exactly the same thing like write here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13586356/5709159 , but I don't understand what is `base` here...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko `base` is just starting address of the buffer from where your `istream` will be reading. You have to allocate this buffer yourself (for example, with `char *buffer = new char[size];`) and fill it with data.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko `istringstream` reads from a string. And string is in RAM. If you put your data in a string, you can use `istringstream` to read the data from RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

Expanding on the code in your question:

```
long size = getFileSize(filename);
std::vector<char> buffer(size);
// here fill the buffer with data
membuf sbuf(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
std::istream file_from_ram(&sbuf);
```

if you'd like to fill the buffer with contenst of some file, do this:

```
std::istream original_file("filename.dat");
original_file.read(buffer.data(), size);
```

Note: this method has problems. First, as @andrew-henle mentioned in comments, file size of type `off_t` which may not fil into `long`. Second, this method suffers from TOCTOU (time of check -- time of use) problem: if file size changes between the call to getFileSize and reading the file, you may be in trouble.

### Option 2

Use `std::istringstream` instead:

```
std::string buffer;
// here fill the string with data
std::istringstream file_from_ram(buffer);
```

If you'd like to fill the buffer with contents of some file, do this (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/116220/4451432):

```
std::ifstream original_file("filename.dat");

std::istringstream file_from_ram;
file_from_ram << original_file.rdbuf();
// Now you can read from file_from_ram
```

Comment: Actually first option that you provided I have already done, but it was intresting to check execution time about second one, and it is takes `*2` more time... I hope it is due to method every call to method make memory allocation for `std::string` where as `std::vector` I declered in `.h` file and just resize it... So, first option faster (as I tested). And also I get error hire `file_from_ram << original_file.rdbuf();` and after I changed `std::istringstream` to `std::stringstream` it works.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you want to read a file.

You need to understand that every variable of your program is stored in your ram. So to "read a file from ram" you just read your file as you are used to.

If the problem is about storing the file in your ram to use it later in another program, it is just not correct. Read the file from the program which need it.

Comment: So, how could you explain this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13586356/5709159 ?

Comment: The answer you sent is about efficiency. Since an entire file can be stored as a C style char pointer, it will obviously take less memory than storing the std::istream class.
If you really want to do it this way you should take a look at [fopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) and [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)