# Stream object directly into a std::string

Tags: c++, string

Given some type that is streamable:

```
struct X {
    int i;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, X const& x) {
        return os << "X(" << x.i << ')';
    }
};
```

I want to append this onto a `std::string`. I can implement this as:

```
void append(std::string& s, X const& x) {
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << x;
    s.append(os.str());
}
```

But this seems lame since I'm writing data into one stream just to then allocate a new string just for the purposes of appending it onto a different one. Is there a more direct route?

Comment: I'd look towards http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/interprocess/streams.html

Comment: Maybe implement `std::string X::repr()` or similar, and call that in both `append` and `operator<<`? Not ideal, but you avoid the intermediate `stringstream`.

Comment: What about simply `s.append(std::string::to_string(x));`? Did I miss something essential?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494182/setting-the-internal-buffer-used-by-a-standard-stream-pubsetbuf) may have some useful information

Comment: Maybe overloading `std::string& operator+=(std::string& s, X const& x)`? This definitely would be more direct ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can be solved by a new type of [`streambuf`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/streambufs.html) (see [Standard C++ IOStreams and Locales: Advanced Programmer's Guide and Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321585585)).

Here is a sketch of how it can look:

```
#include <streambuf>

class existing_string_buf : public std::streambuf
{
public:
    // Store a pointer to to_append.
    explicit existing_string_buf(std::string &to_append); 

    virtual int_type overflow (int_type c) {
        // Push here to the string to_append.
    }
};
```

Once you flesh out the details here, you could use it as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

std::string s;
// Create a streambuf of the string s
existing_string_buf b(s);
// Create an ostream with the streambuf
std::ostream o(&b);
```

Now you just write to `o`, and the result should appear as appended to `s`.

```
// This will append to s
o << 22;
```

**Edit**

As @rustyx correctly notes, overriding `xsputn` is required for improving performance.

**Full Example**

The following prints `22`:

```
#include <streambuf>
#include <string>
#include <ostream> 
#include <iostream>

class existing_string_buf : public std::streambuf
{
public:
    // Somehow store a pointer to to_append.
    explicit existing_string_buf(std::string &to_append) : 
        m_to_append(&to_append){}

    virtual int_type overflow (int_type c) {
        if (c != EOF) {
            m_to_append->push_back(c);
        }
        return c;
    }

    virtual std::streamsize xsputn (const char* s, std::streamsize n) {
        m_to_append->insert(m_to_append->end(), s, s + n);                                                                                 
        return n;
    }

private:
    std::string *m_to_append;
};


int main()
{   
    std::string s;
    existing_string_buf b(s);
    std::ostream o(&b);

    o << 22; 

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: There are times when I feel like I know C++. This is not one of those times.

Comment: Is there any reason to store a pointer and not a reference? Does the buffer have to be copyable?

Comment: @NathanOliver That's a very good point (thanks!), but it unfortunately exceeds my knowledge (the pointer was indeed chosen just so not to risk it). On the one hand, `streambuf` seems to be required to have a copy ctor; on the other hand, the pointer argument of the `ostream` taking it seems to indicate it's not copied. Bottom line - not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a std::string casting operator:

```
struct X {
int i;

friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, X const& x) {
    os << "X(" << x.i << ')';
    return os;
}

operator std::string() {
    return std::string("X(") + std::to_string(x.i) + ")";
}

};
```

Then, you could simply append it to a std::string:

```
X myX;
myX.i = 2;
std::string s("The value is ");
s.append(myX); //myX is cast into the string "X(2)"
```

Comment: Ok but now I have the same logic twice.

Comment: True. Change the first line of the operator<< method to "os << static_cast<string>(x);".

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case I'd just follow the KISS principle:

```
struct X {
    int i;

    std::string toString() const {
        return "X(" + std::to_string(i) + ")";
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
string += x.toString();
std::cout << x.toString();
```

An `operator<<(std::ostream&, …)` isn't really suitable for generic string conversion, so if that's what you're after then a `toString` type of method / free function is much better. And if you want `std::cout << x` you can trivially implement `operator<<` to just call `toString`.

Answer (score -1):

Since the original string is likely only large enough for the existing allocation, the best you can hope for is to format everything you want to append once in the stream, then append the result as you have in your example.

If you plan on performing these appends often, I would argue std::string is the wrong type for the problem at hand. I would recommend using an std::ostringtream directly instead of a std::string, and only convert to a string when you need the final result.