# Stringstream peculiarity must copy entire string twice?

Tags: c++, string, char, std, stringstream

If I open a file and read in a long stream, and I want the data from it, I found out that the following doesn't work, because the `str()` method of a `std::stringstream` returns a copy of a temporary that is destroyed as soon as it returns. So the following doesn't work:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << largeFile.rdbuf();
const char* ptr = ss.str().c_str();       // ptr is a dangling pointer
```

So I actually have to have a temporary `std::string` for the return of `ss.str()` to copy to. This ends up (if I understand it correctly), the copy assignment operator of the string class doing a one for one deep copy between the two `std::string` objects, including the entire buffer it contains. But actually this happening twice because the temporary copy that I discovered gets destructed after `ss.str().c_str()` returns is also a one for one copy.

I'm a bit confused about this. I'm not great at programming and I was trying to figure out a way to avoid copying big buffers. Thanks.

Comment: `char* ptr = ss.str();` doesn't compile, since you can't assign a `std::string` to a `char*`. Just use `std::string s =  = ss.str();` and rely on copy elision on return.

Comment: @  πάντα ῥεῖ Sorry, I meant char* ptr = ss.str().c_str(); Sorry, mistake.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I still think you'll end up with 2 buffers no matter what, as `ss` won't be moved from. You have a typo in the comment, 2 equals, but too late to edit it :)

Comment: @vsoftco It's maybe because I made a mistake in the question, I said char* ptr = ss.str() instead of ss.str().c_str(). Obviously in my code that's what I had, I just missed it when asking the question.

Comment: you might be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752936/stream-object-directly-into-a-stdstring) since you're worried about copying large buffers.