# Logging using c++ stl stringstream with real-time performance requirements

Tags: c++, performance, logging, real-time, stringstream

I'm attempting to implement logging functionality in an application that is required to run in real-time (meaning, spending a few milliseconds writing to a file during execution of the main loop will significantly affect performance since we are interfacing with several systems that require low latency).  My current implementation logs a line into a stringstream object each millisecond, and then writes the resulting string to a file only upon shutdown:

```
class ControlDemo {
  public:
    ControlDemo();
    ~ControlDemo();
    void spin();
    // Other public methods
  private:
    void logLine(std::vector<double> data);
    void writeLogFile();
    std::stringstream m_logged_data;
    std::string m_log_filename;
    bool m_continue_spinning;
    // Other private methods
};

ControlDemo::~ControlDemo() {
  writeLogFile();  // write log data in RAM to a file
}

void ControlDemo::spin() {
  while(m_continue_spinning){
    // do stuff
    logLine(data_to_log);
    sleepRemainingTime();  // maintaining ~1ms loop rate
  }
}

void ControlDemo::logLine(std::vector<double> data) {
  m_logged_data << getCurrentTime();
  for (std::vector<double>::iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
    m_logged_data << ', ' << *it;
  m_logged_data << std::endl;
}

void ControlDemo::writeLogFile() {
  std::ofstream file;
  file.open(m_log_file_path.c_str());

  file << m_logged_data.str();
  file.close();
  std::cerr << "Wrote log to " << m_log_file_path << std::endl;
}
```

My desire is to implement some type of buffering functionality whereby I can specify the maximum number of lines in my log, after which, the initial lines will be discarded (essentially a circular buffer).  In this way, I am not wasting a bunch of RAM and slowing down my application by continuing to accumulate logged data, when maybe only the last 20 seconds of data is important.  I attempted this by modifying the `logLine()` method as follows:

```
void ControlDemo::logLine(std::vector<double> data) {
  static int line_num = 0;
  if(line_num < m_max_num_lines)
    line_num++;
  else  // discard first line before inserting next line
    m_logged_data.ignore(1000,'\n');  // move get ptr to next line

  m_logged_data << getCurrentTime();
  for (std::vector<double>::iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
    m_logged_data << ', ' << *it;
  m_logged_data << std::endl;
}
```

However the `m_logged_data.str()` that is called in `writeLogFile()` still returns all logged data rather than just the last `m_max_num_lines`, which suggests that moving the stringstream get pointer with `ignore()` does not affect the size of the buffer used by the stringstream object or optimize the code in any of the ways that I intended.

I feel like either I am missing something obvious about the `stringstream` class (why isn't there a `setBufferSize()`?? see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494182/setting-the-internal-buffer-used-by-a-standard-stream-pubsetbuf)), or I should be using something else to manage the logging functionality.  If the latter, any suggestions on what class I should be using? One of the nice things about `stringstream` is all of the built-in formatting features, which I am using (although I didn't show it in the code snippets above). So, retaining those formatting capabilities would be nice if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: What formatting requirements do you have?

Comment: how much memory do you have available to hold the logging information?

Answer (score 1):

If you really like to use std::stringstream, you can create an array of std::stringstream and use it as your own ring buffer. Here is a very small example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

class CyclicStreamer {
public:
    CyclicStreamer(int _n, std::string _filename) : n(_n), cur(0), filename(_filename){
        s = new std::stringstream [n];
    };
    ~CyclicStreamer() {
        delete s;
    };
    void LogLine(int data) {
        s[cur].str(std::string()); // clear the stringstream
        s[cur] << data << std::endl;
        cur =  (cur+1) % n;
    }
    void LogToFile(){
        std::ofstream file;
        file.open(filename.c_str());
        for(int i=cur;i<n;i++){
            file << s[i].str();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<cur;i++){
            file << s[i].str();
        }
        file.close();
    }
private:
    int n;
    int cur;
    std::string filename;
    std::stringstream *s;
};

int main() {
    CyclicStreamer cs = CyclicStreamer(10, "log.txt");
    for(int i=0; i<=20; i++){
        cs.LogLine(i);
    }
    cs.LogToFile();
    return 0;
}
```

Do note that if you use the example here in your own project with a pretty large `m_max_num_lines`, you will get into trouble because you might end up using a lot more memories than expected because for each std::stringstream it takes a bit of memory itself. A better way of doing it is to allow each of them to store part of `m_max_num_lines`. Say, if `m_max_num_lines` is 1000, then you can have only 10 std::stringstream, each storing a maximum of 100 lines of log. When a std::stringstram has already stored 100 lines of log, `cur =  (cur+1) % n`.

Do note that it would be much better if you can just use a char array and manage it by yourself. You save both memory and time, but as you said, you lose those built-in formatting features， although there're also very nice features of formatting a raw char array, e.g. `sprintf()`.

Comment: If you are doing real time, hhys last paragraph is dead on.   One allocation/deallocation of an array of fixed size buffers that you store your log message in, with a pointer to say what the next buffer is to be used is likely to be much faster.