# Redirect buffer of string stream to used defined memory

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, stringstream

RT. Typically, the string stream has its own buffer.

```
std::ostringstream stream;
stream << "Hello";
stream.str(); // It's "Hello"
```

Then how to redirect the buffer inside the string stream to my own allocated memory like this,

```
 std::string *buffer = new std::string;
 std::ostringstream stream;
 stream.rdbuf( buffer );
 stream.str(); // It's "Hello"
 buffer->c_str(); // It's also "Hello"
```

Comment: Have you seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494182/setting-the-internal-buffer-used-by-a-standard-stream-pubsetbuf)?

Comment: Why would you want to do this rather than just using a hard [`std::basic_stringbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf)

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/iostreams/doc/tutorial/container_sink.html