# How to feed binary hex literal into std::istream?

Tags: c++, binary, hex, istream

I have a method `deserialize` taking a reference to opened `std::istream` where normally I pass in an `std::ifstream` opened with `std::ios::binary` option.

Now I would like to test it with some binary (hex) literals but I do not know how to feed that data into the `std::istream`.

I tried something similar like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7782037/675100)

```
struct membuf : std::streambuf
{
  membuf(char* begin, char* end)
  {
    this->setg(begin, begin, end);
  }
};

int main()
{
  char buffer[] = "0a0b0c0d000000480000000000420410000";

  membuf sbuf(buffer, buffer + sizeof(buffer) - 1);
  std::istream in(&sbuf);

  deserialize(in);
}
```

Which fails because that data is not read/fed as binary.

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you forgotten about `std::istringstream`?

Comment: @LogicStuff can you explain how to use it in here?

Comment: I misunderstood a bit. You've just got the answer.

Comment: @LogicStuff that's what I thought ;d I don't think I can use `istringstream` here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any binary data in your `buffer`, but characters. You have a plain c-style character literal.

To feed your input from binary data you need a declaration like this:

```
unsigned char buffer[] = { 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x00, 0x00, 
                            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x42, 0x04, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

Comment: This did the trick with `struct membuf` and `std::streambuf` stuff

Comment: I am sorry but how do you get this buffer into a istream data type? That's the question, i'm also stuck on this problem.