# How to send data from char array to istream in class C++

Tags: c++, istream

i want to send data f char array from main function to a istream member of a class as following code:

```
class StreamClass {
    public:
        std::shared_ptr<std::istream> istream_ptr;
};
int main(){    
    StreamClass sc;    
    char charArray[] = "hello world";
    sc.istream_ptr = std::make_shared<std::istream>(nullptr);   
}
```

i read this link [Get an istream from a char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781898/get-an-istream-from-a-char) . However i want to do it without coding anything manually , just using simple std functions. is it possible.

Answer (score 1):

The shared pointer is a bit overhead for this question. You need to deference it. Then you need to convert your array into a pointer. You also might want to create an out stream instead of an in stream, from your question. :

```
#include "iostream"
#include "memory"

class StreamClass {
    public:
        std::shared_ptr<std::istream> istream_ptr;
        std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> ostream_ptr;
};
int main(){
    StreamClass sc;
    char charArray[] = "hello world";
    sc.istream_ptr = std::make_shared<std::istream>(nullptr);
    sc.ostream_ptr = std::make_shared<std::ostream>(nullptr);
    std::cout << &(charArray[0]) << std::endl;
    *sc.ostream_ptr << &(charArray[0]);
    *sc.istream_ptr >> &(charArray[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jan Hackenberg.  i was checking  StreamClass sc in debug mode after charArray. But it seems the data actually was not stored inside istream_ptr .

Comment: @user5005768Himadree In my answers code, the data from `charArray` should be stored in ` ostream_ptr`, see operator `<<`. Then the content of `istream_ptr`, which is zero is flushed into `charArray`, see operator `>>`. `>>` is not defined for  `std::istream`, only for `std::ostream`.