# How to create streambuf with array of unsigned char in C++

Tags: c++, istream, streambuf

I want to create a [std::istream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/) object with a stream buffer object that can take raw byte data from array of unsigned char. I searched and found this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781898/get-an-istream-from-a-char)

However they create the stream buffer based on array char:

```
struct membuf : std::streambuf
{
    membuf(char* begin, char* end) {
        this->setg(begin, begin, end);
    }
};
```

I thought about type caste , but i don't want to modify the original data.So how i can it be done using unsigned char.

Comment: You can just cast the pointers to `char*` when you create `membuf`. It will not modify the data.

Comment: whatever signed or unsigned, that changes nothing when you use your stream

Answer (score 1):

With `std::istream` you cannot use `unsigned char` explicitly, because it is a typedef for `std::basic_istream<char>` [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream). You can cast your buffer pointers to `char*`

```
this->setg(reinterpret_cast<char*>(begin), reinterpret_cast<char*>(begin), reinterpret_cast<char*>(end));
```

Note that conversion of values greater than `CHAR_MAX` to `char` is [implementaion defined](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3) (of course, only if you will actually use this values as `char`).

Or you can try to use `std::basic_istream<unsigned char>` (I have not tried it though).