# convert from string to byte[] and add the result into a memorystream

Tags: c++, ubuntu

how can i convert a string into a byte[] and them add the result using in a stream. THX. I am working in c++ code, ubuntu.

EDIT:
i have a std::string as a string value.
I need a method that takes as an input a std::string value and returns as an output the stream value.

Comment: what type of `string`?  `std::string`, `char*`, `wchar_t*`, ...?

Comment: Not enough information. Give a concrete example of your input and you expected output. Also, I don't think you have C++ there, as it does not have a `byte`-datatype. There is also no `memorystream`-class that I know of in C++.

Comment: @justM: Could it be that you are actually using C# or managed C++?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079912/simpler-way-to-create-a-c-memorystream-from-char-size-t-without-copying-th

Comment: i've re edite my code. i am using c++. please give a concrete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a pointer to the string buffer by simply calling `std::string.c_str()`.  That will return a `const char*` (where `char` is an `int8_t`) that you can effectively use as a `byte[]`.  Keep in mind though that the pointer returned is pointing to memory managed by the string object, so if you change anything in the original string class, you will invalidate the pointer.  Also since it's a pointer to a `const char`, you shouldn't change any values in the buffer.  So if you need more permanent memory, or need a buffer you can modify, a better way to accomplish your goal would be to-do (using gcc, which shouldn't be a problem since you're on Ubuntu):

```
std::string my_string;
char string_array[my_string.length() + 1];
strcpy(string_array, my_string.c_str());
```

Now use the `string_array` as your memory buffer.

If you need to return the buffer from a function, you're going to have to allocate the buffer on the heap and return a pointer.  That also means you're going to have to call `delete []` on the pointer as well after you're done with it, or else you're going to end up with a memory leak.  So you could do the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

char* return_buffer(const std::string& string)
{
   char* return_string = new char[string.length() + 1];
   strcpy(return_string, string.c_str());

   return return_string;
}

//now use in code
int main()
{
    std::string some_string = "Stuff";
    char* buffer = return_buffer(some_string);

    //...do something with buffer

    //...after you're done with the buffer to prevent memory leak
    delete [] buffer;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thx for the answer. how can i put this in a method that returns the string_array ?

Comment: can you plese post an example?

Answer (score 0):

As Space_C0wb0y pointed out, C++ doesn't have a `byte` datatype. C# has one though. Is that the language you want?

If you're sure that you are dealing with C++, then I guess you'd be using the `char` datatype which is one byte in size. Also, to convert a `std::string` to `char*` (a pointer to a bunch of `char` values, terminated by `\0`), you have to call the `c_str()` function on the variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by `byte`: `char` or `unsigned char`?  And
I'm not familiar with your `memorystream` either.  But assuming that you
have an `std:;string`, and you want to append it to an
`std::vector<unsigned char>`, you can use `std::copy` directly:

```
std::copy( input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter( out ) );
```

If some sort of translation is required, `std::transform` might be
usable, as long as it's one `char` to one `byte`.

Comment: You _are_ aware that the `back_inserter` will `push_back` repeatedly, which may (and will) cause memory allocations?  You can remedy this by `out.reserve( input.size() )`.

Comment: Sure, but why bother?  It's easy to add if the profiler shows that the allocations and copy are a bottleneck, but until then, keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use c_str() on your string to access the string content as a const char*, which should be what you need. Possibly you will need then a cast, but it should be ok, since a char is (usually, and it is on your platform) 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<char> bytes(myString.begin(), myString.end());
```

is a simple solution