# C++ converting file stream function to use a stringstream

Tags: c++, ifstream, stringstream

I have loads of c++ classes that reads data from a file stream. The functions looks like this.

```
bool LoadFromFile(class ifstream &file);
```

I'm creating a new function to read from memory instead of a file. So I googled around and a istringstream seems to do the trick without any modifications to the code.

```
bool LoadFromData(class istringstream &file);
```

Now my question is. I need to construct this stream to read from a char array. The string is not null-terminated, it's pure binary data and I got a integer with the size. I tried assigning it to a string and creating a stream from a string, however the string terminates after a null character.. and the data is copied.

```
int size;
char *data;
string s = *data;
```

How do I create a string from a char array pointer without copying the data + specifying the size of the pointer data? Do you know any other solution than a stringstream?

Comment: So, clarification: Is your problem that your `char *` is not null terminated and therefore you're having trouble constructing an `std::string` out of it?

Comment: Yea that's the problem basically. I'm also wondering if anyone knows a better solution.

Comment: Here is maybe the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079912/simpler-way-to-create-a-c-memorystream-from-char-size-t-without-copying-th (one version uses boost, on copies the data and one only works with gcc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write an own `basic_streambuf` class! [More details.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h24a8cd%28VS.80%29.aspx). (This way you could work on the current memory.)

To create string from pointer and size: `string str(data,data+size);` (it will copy the data).

On more thing: you should rewrite your functions to based on `istream`:

```
bool LoadFromStream(istream &is);
```

In this way you could do the followings, because both `istringstream` and `ifstream` based on `istream` (later this function could also supports tcp streams...):

```
ifstream file;
istringstream sstream;

LoadFromStream(file);
LoadFromStream(sstream);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my problem without changing the functions at all!

Comment: Seems like it worked for the file streams but when I passed a string stream to it I got this compiler error (with the exact code above). I did my best to research it but I just don't get it. It's compiled in VS.              

cannot convert parameter 1 from 'class std::basic_istringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >' to 'class istream &'

Comment: I use it in many places. You should define as `bool LoadFromStream(istream &is);` against `bool LoadFromStream(class istream &is);` In header file I usually not use `using namespace std;` so the definition is: `bool LoadFromStream(std::istream &is);`. You should include `<istream>`.