# const char * to std::basic_iostream

Tags: c++, c++11, stream, std, aws-sdk

I have a pointer to a `const *char` buffer as well as it's length, and am trying to use an API (in this case, the [AWS S3 C++ upload request](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/3bd938d852eb812a59167980fa7ef292999d080a/aws-cpp-sdk-core/include/aws/core/AmazonStreamingWebServiceRequest.h#L54)) that accepts an object of type:

```
std::basic_iostream <char, std::char_traits <char>>
```

Is there a simple standard C++11 way to convert my buffer into a compatible stream, preferably without actually copying over the memory?

Comment: When you say `I have a pointer to a const *char buffer` do you really mean that you have a pointer to a `const char* buffer[N]`, or did you intend to say that you have a pointer to a (zero terminated?) buffer of characters?

Comment: @user2079303 - The latter. It's a binary data buffer so it's not necessarily zero terminated.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079912/simpler-way-to-create-a-c-memorystream-from-char-size-t-without-copying-t)  question looks related to me

Comment: @UKMonkey - Indeed, however, one solution involves boost which I can't currently use, and the second (pubsetbuf) doesn't work for const char.

Comment: [`std::strstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/strstream) can do that, but it's deprecated. The non-deprecated counterpart is [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream), but it can't work off a client-provided buffer - it always makes a copy.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Igor's comment, this seems to work:

```
func(const * char buffer, std::size_t buffersize)
{     
    auto sstream = std::make_shared<std::stringstream>();
    sstream->write(buffer, buffersize);
    ...
    uploadRequest.SetBody(sstream);     
    ....
```

Comment: @MarkR - Probably best to add this as an answer.

Comment: I thought this was the answer I, too, was looking for. But it doesn't compile: `no member named 'write' in 'std::__1::basic_istringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >'`

Comment: Actually, it does compile if you use the `std::stringstream::out` flag when calling `make_shared`.

Comment: FYI It helped me answer my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666549/upload-uint8-t-buffer-to-aws-s3-without-going-via-filesystem/48926299#48926299

Comment: Doesn't `->write` do a copy of the data, though? I'm still looking for a copyless solution, will post if I succeed.

Answer (score 2):

As a fairly obvious corollary to your solution, you can create an empty basic_iostream with code like this. This example creates a 0-byte pseudo-directory S3 key:

```
Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest object_request; 
// dirName ends in /.             
object_request.WithBucket(bucketName).WithKey(dirName); 
// Create an empty input stream to create the 0-byte directory file. 
auto empty_sstream = std::make_shared<std::stringstream>();    
object_request.SetBody(empty_sstream); 
auto put_object_outcome = s3_client->PutObject(object_request);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do **not** want to make a copy of your data, and assuming using boost is an option, you can use basic_bufferstream from boost:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/streams/bufferstream.hpp>
char* buf = nullptr; // get your buffer
size_t length = 0; 
auto input = Aws::MakeShared<boost::interprocess::basic_bufferstream<char>> (
             "PutObjectInputStream",                                         
             buf,                                                            
             length);
```

Then your s3 client can use it:

```
 Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest req;
 req.WithBucket(bucket).WithKey(key);
 req.SetBody(input);
 s3.PutObject(req);
```