# Upload uint8_t* buffer to AWS S3 without going via filesystem

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**Disclaimers:**
I am not a c++ programmer, please save me from myself.

I'm trying to create a PutObjectRequest in c++ using the AWS SDK.

I have a 'uint8_t*' (in Java-land from whence I hail we call this a byte[], I believe on planet c++ this is a buffer), and I need to get it into an Aws::IOStream somehow.

All of the examples show the data coming directly from the filesystem.

I've seen a couple of similar-ish (but not really) questions with answers that point to another third party library called Boost, but *surely* this is a common usecase? Why would I need a third party library to do something that should just be possible using the AWS SDK?:

*"I have data, I want to put it up on S3. No it's not in the filesystem, yes I created it in memory."*

```
uint8_t* buf; //<-- How do I get this...
...
Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest object_request;
object_request.WithBucket(output_bucket).WithKey(key_name);

object_request.SetBody(data); //<-- ...into here
```

I really appreciate any help or pointers (no pun intended) here.

**Update** 
I've tried everything in the comments, and this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Aws::IOStream> objectStream = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::StringStream>("PutObjectInputStream");        
*objectStream << data;
objectStream->flush();
object_request.SetBody(objectStream);
```

and this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Aws::IOStream> objectStream = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::StringStream>("PutObjectInputStream");        
std::istringstream is((char*) data);
*objectStream << is.rdbuf();
objectStream->flush();
object_request.SetBody(objectStream);
```

which compile, but each only uploads 2 bytes of data.

Other thing I've tried that don't compile are:

```
auto input_data = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::IOStream>("PutObjectInputStream", std::istringstream((char*) data), std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
object_request.SetBody(input_data);
```

and

```
object_request.SetBody(std::make_shared<std::istringstream>( std::istringstream( (char*) spn ) ));
```

and these ones creates the object on S3, but with 0 bytes:

```
    std::shared_ptr<Aws::IOStream> objectStream = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::StringStream>("PutObjectInputStream");
    objectStream->rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(static_cast<char*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data)), length);
    objectStream->rdbuf()->pubseekpos(length);
    objectStream->seekg(0);
    object_request.SetBody(objectStream);


    std::shared_ptr<Aws::IOStream> objectStream = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::StringStream>("PutObjectInputStream");
    objectStream->rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), length);
    objectStream->rdbuf()->pubseekpos(length);
    objectStream->seekg(0);
    object_request.SetBody(objectStream);
```

Comment: Please provide a reference to `SetBody` method. [First link in google](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/0.12.9/df/da6/class_aws_1_1_s3_1_1_model_1_1_put_object_request.html) does not contain it.

Comment: It's in the AWS SDK documentation, right here: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/0.12.9/dd/dd8/class_aws_1_1_amazon_streaming_web_service_request.html

Sorry, I thought I made it clear that this was an AWS S3 PutObjectRequest.

Comment: It seems you can use something like `object_request.SetBody( std::istringstream( (char*) data ) );`, but I'm unable to test it myself and not sure this is the best solution.

Comment: Thank you for checking it. Unfortunately it doesn't compile: `error: no viable conversion from 'std::istringstream' (aka 'basic_istringstream<char>') to 'const std::shared_ptr<Aws::IOStream>'
      (aka 'const shared_ptr<basic_iostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >')`

Comment: What if you replace `std::istringstream` with `std::make_shared<std::istringstream>`?

Comment: That results in this: `address of overloaded function 'make_shared' does not match required type 'std::__1::shared_ptr<std::__1::basic_iostream<char> >'`

Comment: You need to actually call `make_shared`

Comment: @BenVoigt like this: `object_request.SetBody(std::make_shared<std::istringstream>( std::istringstream( (char*) data ) )>);` ?

Comment: @ndtreviv: No, `make_shared<T>` doesn't take a parameter of type `T`, but those needed to create a `T` (the parameters for `T`'s constructor).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

And after *hours* of hacking, here is the answer:

```
    Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest object_request;
    object_request.WithBucket(output_bucket).WithKey(key_name);
    auto data = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::StringStream>("PutObjectInputStream", std::stringstream::in | std::stringstream::out | std::stringstream::binary);
    data->write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), length);
    object_request.SetBody(data);
```

Thanks to [Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt) for pointing out that when you `make_shared` (or `MakeShared` in my case), you're not actually passing it the data at that point. You're just telling it what `T` you're making shared.

Also helped by nbubis' answer to this question: [const char * to std::basic_iostream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41448626/const-char-to-stdbasic-iostream)

Comment: If you have a vector of user define struct/lass then the following works:         
        auto data = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::StringStream>("PutObjectInputStream", std::stringstream::in | std::stringstream::out | std::stringstream::binary);
        data->write((char*)&vec[0], vec.size() * sizeof(MyData));
        object_request.SetBody(data);