# How to initialise std::istringstream from const unsigned char* without cast or copy?

Tags: c++, strstream

I have binary data in a byte sequence described by `const unsigned char *p` and `size_t len`.  I want to be able to pass this data to a function that expects a `std::istream *`.

I think I should be able to do this without copying the data, unsafe casts or writing a new stream class.  But so far I'm failing.  Can anyone help?

**Update**

Thanks all for the comments.  This would seem to be an unanswerable question because `std::istream` operates with `char` and conversion would at some point require at least an integer cast from `unsigned char`.

The pragmatic approach is to do this:

```
std::string s(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(p), len);
std::istringstream i(s);
```

and pass `&i` to the function expecting `std::istream *`.

Comment: Possibly see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448467/initializing-a-c-stdistringstream-from-an-in-memory-buffer

Comment: Have you actually profiled the code and found that copying the data is the problem?  I suspect you'll be better off if you just copy the data and forget about it.

Comment: @Tom Performance of copy is not an issue but memory usage of maintaining two copies might be - and in any case, copying needs a cast as I understand it.

Comment: The reason the cast from `unsigned char*` to `char*` is unsafe, is because of the hypothetical existence of non-2's-complement implementations. On 1s' complement or sign-magnitude, `*(signed char*)p != (signed char)*p;`, where `p` is an `unsigned char*` and the referand has the top bit set. If you want to avoid this "unsafe" reinterpretation, you have to perform an unsigned-signed conversion elsewhere. To avoid a copy as well, I think that would mean writing a stream, since AFAIK there isn't anything in the standard libraries that reads from an `unsigned char*`.

Comment: Oh, and a further point, the conversion from `unsigned char` to `char` is itself slightly "unsafe" because of those same implementations - if `char` is signed neither one of them can represent `-128` (assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8`), so how is the unsigned value `128` going to be converted to signed? The standard leaves the result of converting values greater than `CHAR_MAX` implementation-defined.

Comment: The stream class may want to fiddle with its internal buffer. So you can pass it a const buffer. Unless you write your own.

Comment: @paperjam: What about using `std::basic_istringstream<unsigned char> i(p);` instead? Does that no work?

Comment: Answering myself, apparently, it does not work OOTB: http://ideone.com/pKe1o

Comment: You could avoid the copy using istrstream rather than istringstream - it operates directly on the memory rather than a copy.  istrstream is deprecated in the STL but it should still be there.

Comment: wilx: isn't the `bad_cast` exception in your code caused by the line before your `basic_istringstream<unsigned char>`? I don't see why your plan would have to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is still copying.

Have you considered something like this?

```
const unsigned char *p;
size_t len;

std::istringstream str;
str.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(
    reinterpret_cast<char*>(const_cast<unsigned char*>(p)), len);
```