# Interfacing with a vector<char> as a stream using binary write() read()

Tags: c++

I'm currently investigating portable, idiomatic, standard library-only C++ methods of writing binary data into a `std::vector<char>`. I would like to interface with the container in the same manner as I would any other binary ostream, using the write() function.

So far the only thing I have turned up is inheriting from `std::basic_streambuf<>`. Are there any better alternatives to this?

Comment: I recall someone asking a similar question for `std::string`.  Dunno if [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39380374/1553090) is helpful to you, but have a look anyway.

Comment: You may find the `char_array_buffer` example useful here: http://www.mr-edd.co.uk/blog/beginners_guide_streambuf

Comment: why `vector`? `std::string` isn't good enough?

Comment: @n.m. It may be a better fit. I certainly don't see any disadvantages to using `std::string` over `vector`.

Comment: So you have std::stringstream to use with std::string

Comment: @n.m. Hmm, I was somehow under the impression that stringstream did not support ``ss.write( &myInt,sizeof( myInt );``

Comment: It does. It is an iostream like any other.

Comment: @n.m. Annoyingly, the ``write`` function seems to be skipping bytes which share the same value as whitespace characters here. I suppose this behavior can be inhibited by ``<< std::noskipws``.

Comment: "write function seems to be skipping bytes" Write function doesn't skip anything. If you have a problem using stringstream, ask a question.

Comment: @n.m. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022801/stringstream-write-skipping-whitespace

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, inheriting from `std::basic_streambuf` is the way to do it. Not sure if you are interested, but boost::iostreams and boost::interprocess have implemented this type of stuff already:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/interprocess/streams.html