# stringstream write skipping whitespace

Tags: c++

I was under the impression that the unformatted `write()` would copy bytes verbatim to the `ostream` on which it is called. I was also told by another SO user that 'Write function doesn't skip anything. If you have a problem using `stringstream`, ask a question.'

However, in some recent code using `stringstream` I found this not to be the case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    {
        const std::string msg = "This is a secret message!";
        std::stringstream ss;
        const int size = msg.size();
        // ss << std::noskipws;
        ss.write( reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&size),sizeof( size ) );
        ss.write( msg.data(),msg.size() );

        std::ofstream out( "secret.txt",std::ios::binary );
        std::transform( std::istream_iterator<char>( ss ),std::istream_iterator<char>(),
                        std::ostream_iterator<char>( out ),[]( const char c ) { return c + 113; } );
    }

    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        std::ifstream in( "secret.txt",std::ios::binary );
        std::transform( std::istream_iterator<char>( in ),std::istream_iterator<char>(),
                        std::ostream_iterator<char>( ss ),[]( const char c ) { return c - 113; } );
        int size;
        ss.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size),sizeof( size ) );
        std::string msg( size,'@' );
        ss.read( &msg[0],size );
        std::cout << "Decoded message is: " << msg << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output for this code is as follows:

> Decoded message is: Thisisasecretmessage!@@@@

However, if I uncomment the `ss << std::noskipws;` line then the output is as expected, with whitespace characters preserved.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are overengineering your test case. Try `std::string check = ss.str();` after the write.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `write` or `stringstream`.

> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator
>
> When reading characters, `std::istream_iterator` skips whitespace by default (unless disabled with `std::noskipws` or equivalent), while `std::istreambuf_iterator` does not. In addition, `std::istreambuf_iterator` is more efficient, since it avoids the overhead of constructing and destructing the sentry object once per character.